# Error: "Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished" when try to modify in a loop

Tags: indexeddb

I´m working with IndexedDB and when I try to modify/edit several values with the same text and using a "FOR" loop it shows me: "Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished".

When I try it with just one value without loops all works fine. This is my actual function:

```
function modificarModelos(){
      var active = dataBase.result;
      var data = active.transaction(["modelos"], "readwrite");
      var object = data.objectStore("modelos");
      var request;
      for(var key in window.idModelosMarca){
        request = object.get(window.idModelosMarca[key]);
        request.onsuccess = function() {
          var data = request.result;   //---> THE ERROR APPEARS IN THIS LINE
          data.idmarca = document.querySelector("#NuevoNombreMarca").value
          var requestActualizado = object.put(data);
          requestActualizado.onsuccess = function() {
            console.log("Success");
          };
          requestActualizado.onerror = function (e) {
            alert(request.error.name + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
          };
        };
      }
    }
```

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it calling that function through another one which have the loop inside:

```
function aux(){
   ....
   for(i=0;i<someCounter;i++){
      modificarModelos(somevalue);       
   }       
}
```

Comment: Yep, that will work. The problem in the original code is that `request` is a single variable that all instances of the callback function point at. So when the first success event fires, `request` will be referencing the last request made.

Another solution is to avoid referencing `request` in the callback, e.g. `onsuccess = function(e) { var data = e.target.result; ... }`

Comment: I've seen this error quite a few times while using indexedDB with functional programs. Joshua's answer is the most accurate I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are new to async programming. The simplest, shortest, and easiest way I think to solve this is *avoid defining functions within loops*.